# Using an arbitrary number of query params to filter results in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building an API using node express and mongodb, with mongoose.
I have a post resource that handles user posts, and would like to be able to perform various queries on the post resource.
For instance I have a functions as that returns all posts as follows:

```
// Gets a list of Posts
exports.index = function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.query);
  Post.findAsync()
    .then(mUtil.responseWithResult(res))
    .catch(mUtil.handleError(res));
};
```

I looking for a good way of processing any additional query params that might come with the request.

`/posts` will return all posts, but `/posts?user=12` will return posts by user with id 12 and `/posts?likes=12` will return posts with 12 or more likes.

How can I check for and apply the these query params to filter and return the results since they may or may not be present.
Thanks ;)

Comment: What are you asking here? If you use `/posts?user=12&likes=12` then how to turn that into your query? You can of course just feed in `req.params`, but of course if "likes" is meant to be "greater than" the specified number then you will need to manipulate that object. MongoDB queries are just object structures, therefore any object manipulation code applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `user=12` means "users with id 12", how does `likes=12` mean "likes greater than 12"? You need to be more descriptive with your queries. You can do that by passing an array of objects. Send your query in a way that can be interpreted like this:

```
var filters = [
{
    param: "likes",
    type: "greater"
    value: 12
},
{
    param: "user",
    type: "equal",
    value: "12"
}]

var query = Post.find();

filters.forEach(function(filter) {

    if (filter.type === "equal") {
        query.where(filter.param).equals(filter.value);
    }
    else if (filter.type === "greater") {
        query.where(filter.param).gt(filter.value);
    }
    // etc,,,
})

query.exec(callback);
```